# USB ports no longer work on the hp dx5150s (slimline)

Tags: usb

On my pc,  all USB ports no longer work on the hp dx5150s (slimline).

I have checked all the USB devices and they work on other PC's. I have made sure all USB ports are enabled on the BIOS.

If you know how to fix this issue, i will be more than appreciative.

Comment: So maybe you could tell us what operating system you're running?

Comment: Static electricity through my mouse killed the usb chip on my laptop last week. It will take a mobo change to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

Type "device manager" in the run box and look for USB devices. If they have any ! or ? next to them, delete them, refresh with F5, and see if that resolves it.

Either you have a driver issue, a virus, or the hardware is fried (or some bad software jamming up all USB). Usually when ALL the ports go together, if the above doesn't work, it's been a dead USB hub, unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all the responses.

But it turns out one of DDR memory chip was bad. So once I playing with the memory slots and removed the bad memory and rebooted again , Windows XP started up and all USB devices got picked up.

Thanks again!